# Preserve colors with watch -n

Tags: logging, tail, watch

I am running

```
watch tail -n 15     20151217.log
```

and my output looks like

```
12-17 04:42:52 DEBUG [31mXYZT    10  91.5[0m
```

Instead, I want to see it as colored text. What can I do?

I don't want to use simply tail -n, because it somehow skips lines and stalls.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also relevant: Many programs disable coloring (`--color=auto` or similar) when they detect output is being redirected.

Answer (score 1):

The manual page for [`watch`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/watch.1.html) lists this option:

```
   -c, --color
          Interpret ANSI color and style sequences.
```

So you could change your command to

```
watch -c tail -n 15     20151217.log
```

and see the color as intended.

In preparing answer, I tested with Debian 7, which uses *procps-ng*.
Scientific Linux uses an older version of *procps* (the set of programs containing `watch`).  Debian uses the newer version cited in the manual page.  For reference, Scientific Linux 6 uses the "latest" version from the [SourceForge project](http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/procps/procps/) which was forked several years ago [here](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/Documentation/bugs.md).  The history for [watch.c](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/watch.c) and [watch.1](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/watch.1) show that the color option was added in [2011](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/commit/39a2f5d717e780d53472daff6fde8184f76b1c91) in *procps-ng*.

The older version from *procps* has no ability to filter escape sequences.

Comment: I have scientific linux.

watch --c tail -n 15     20151218.log 
watch: unrecognized option '--c'
Usage: watch [-dhntv] [--differences[=cumulative]] [--help] [--interval=<n>] [--no-title] [--version] <command>